# Why does hclust gives a different cluster than pvclust in r?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to get the p-values for hierarchical clustering analysis on the following dataset.The dendrograms generated by pvclust and hclust are completely different.Because the pvclust mentioned they used the same method as hclust, it should be identical.

```
require(vegan) 
test

  S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
4  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   1
5  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
6  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1
7  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1   0
8  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   0
9  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   0

div.norm=decostand(test,"normalize")
div.ch=vegdist(div.norm,"bray")
div.ch.UPGMA=hclust(div.ch,method = "average")
plot(div.ch.UPGMA)
```

This generates the following dendrogram:
[Cluster using hclust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UTV6.jpg)
Then I tried to run the same dataset using pvclust.

```
require(pvclust)
test.tr=t(test)
result=pvclust(test.tr, method.dist="cor", method.hclust="average", nboot=1000)
plot(result)
```

I get the following dendrogram which is different from the one generated by hclust. [cluster using pvclust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPVJ6.jpg)

Some suggested that I should not transpose the data. But that produces a dendrogram where the columns are clustered (I don't want that).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use `dput` to share your data in a reproducible way (see the R tag description). Also, just for future reference, we prefer that you don't include the `>` when you show your code, so that it can be copy and pasted without editing.

Comment: Your code shows that you use normalized data for hclust and "bray" distance. In pvclust, the distance is "cor" and data not normalized. Does the problem remain with identical methods and data pre-processing?

Comment: @nya: It does not accept "bray" in pvclust as a valid entry for method.dist.

Comment: @user127213 Then you need to choose a method according to the analysis requirement. If you use different methods, the functions should return different results.

Answer (score 2):

The `pvclust` implementation of hierchical clustering that you're using relies on bootstrap resampling. This introduces a degree of randomness and you could get different results between 2 runs of `pvclust` thus you should expect it to be precisely the same as `hclust`.

Moreover, you may have noticed some fairly serious warnings while running `pvclust`:

> ```
> Bootstrap (r = 0.5)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 0.6)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 0.7)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 0.8)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 0.9)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 1.0)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 1.1)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 1.2)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 1.3)... Done.
> Bootstrap (r = 1.4)... Done.
> Warning messages:
> 1: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  0.5 
> 2: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  0.6 
> 3: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  0.7 
> 4: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  0.8 
> 5: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  0.9 
> 6: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  1 
> 7: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  1.1 
> 8: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  1.2 
> 9: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  1.3 
> 10: inappropriate distance matrices are omitted in computation: r =  1.4
> ```

As every iteration of the `pvclust` has an unusable distance matrix the results should be interpreted with extreme caution and this could invalidate them and change them significantly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. However, I am not sure it is a problem of the iterations. I would expect to find identical result atleast once if I run it over 15 times. Interestingly, the dendrograms created using pvclust are very consistent and never changes in configuration. They are unique and different from the one generated by hclust.

Comment: @user127213 You're welcome, but asides from the randomness at every sampling don't forget that *the result was entirely invalid because of the inappropriate distance matrices*. That's definitely **non-trivial**. Also, you might be a little bit overly optimistic to think that you can get an identical result just because it ran 15 (or 1,500) times. If it were not for the algorithm breaking due to the distance matrices you could probably get a *close* result but there's no reason that it would be *identical*.